# Can only concatenate str not list to str

Tags: python, string, typeerror

I want to concatenate a part of a string in list but got Type error

Code

```
l = [['----Italy', '----Spain', '----France']]

for n in l:
    print("Hi "+n[4:]+" Country")

TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "list") to str
```

Comment: i think it's generally frowned upon to use `_` as a var outside of list comprehension etc. And using `__` just makes it hard to read

Comment: `__` is a list, not an element of the nested list. You could see this for yourself by simply inserting `print(__)` at the top of the loop body.

Comment: ``[['----Italy', '----Spain', '----France']]`` is a list of strings *inside another list*. Use ``['----Italy', '----Spain', '----France']`` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you made a list of lists at the beginning for some reason

```
_ = ['----Italy', '----Spain', '----France']
```

Answer (score 1):

try the below:

```
_ = ['----Italy', '----Spain', '----France']

for __ in _:
    print("Hi "+ "".join(__[4:]) +" Country")
```

Output:

```
Hi Italy Country
Hi Spain Country
Hi France Country
```

Comment: this does get rid of the error, but just returns `Hi  Country`

Comment: What is the desired output ?

Comment: i assume OP wants `Hi Italy Country` etc for each country is his list

Comment: Just Edited the answer. should be working now

Comment: yea that works. the downvote wasn't me but thats it

Comment: Great ! - Consider accepting the answer ;)

Comment: Why the ``"".join``? ``__[4:]`` is already a string with this setup.

Answer (score 1):

You are iterating over the only element of the list _, which is also a list.

Try this:

```
_ = ['----Italy', '----Spain', '----France']
for __ in _:
    print("Hi "+__[4:]+" Country")
```

Answer (score 0):

Without changing the list, you can just loop through the sublists too

```
_ = [['----Italy', '----Spain', '----France']]

for i in _:
    for j in i:
        print("Hi "+__[4:]+" Country")
```

Comment: Using a second loop instead of just unrolling the input or indexing is a waste. On a sidenote, there is no ``__`` defined in the loop anymore.

Comment: Oh ok.  I wasnt sure if this list was created by a loop from the computer or if it was inputted